# Blender 3.3 does not recognize my GPU for HIP (on Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, gpu, blender

My GPU (RX 5600 XT) does not appear as an option in Blender Render Devices menu. It reads:

> No compatible GPUs found for Cycles. Requires AMD GPU with Vega or RDNA architecture and AMD driver version 22.10 or newer

My card does meet those requirements and I have `Radeon™ Software for Linux® installer version 22.20 for Ubuntu 20.04.5 HWE` installed. I have a similar issue with DaVinci Resolve.

The interesting thing is that when I run blender as root, Both my GPU and CPU appear as options.

Additionally, using `clinfo` will result in (this is obviously not everything):

> Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing

> Number of devices                                 0

However, using `clinfo` as root will result in:

> Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing

> Number of devices                                 1

Edit: Blender will output `HIP hipInit: Invalid device` to the terminal if preferences is opened.
Edit 2: I've added myself to the `video` and `render` groups, to no avail.

Here is some information I get from `lspci -vnn`

````
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] [1682:5710]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 77
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at fcd00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at fcd80000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu```
````

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue. After doing all of the things above, what finally worked was logging out, then restarting my device.

It probably also helped that I ran this beforehand:
`sudo usermod -a -G video username`
`sudo usermod -a -G render username`