# Loads of issues after installing AMD GPU on KDE Neon

Tags: drivers, graphics, kde, amd-graphics, gpu

I've just bought an AMD Radeon RX 7900 XT and now I'd quite like to use it. Issue is, I've researched possible drivers which I may need and realised that `amdgpu` is already bundled with the kernel. Installing the GPU and running `sudo lspci -v` gives the [following information](https://gist.github.com/J-Cake/d23bab30954b2629131d638dc58ffbeb#file-out-log-L285-L308) (important extract below):

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 31 [Radeon RX 7900 XT/7900 XTX] (rev cc) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1002
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 197
        Memory at 4800000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32G]
        Memory at 4400000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=256]
        Memory at 85500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Expansion ROM at 85600000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
        Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [200] Physical Resizable BAR
        Capabilities: [240] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
        Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
        Capabilities: [2d0] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        Capabilities: [320] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [410] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
        Capabilities: [450] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Clearly it's being detected and the correct drivers loaded (amdgpu - can't get more descriptive than that)

However various issues arise.

For one, any application which has inbuilt support for hardware acceleration (ie all Chromium-based programs, including all Electron stuff and Blender as well) crashes all of KDE plasma. It restarts within a second or so with all programs shut - this typically means that `kwin_wayland` crashed, taking down any processes it started with it - including plasma, and since plasma starts all apps, those as well.

Secondly, with the AMDGPU drivers installed additionally using AMD's documentation, various other things arise:

1. `kwin_wayland`, `plasmashell` and a few other processes consume upwards of 75% of my CPU **each** (this is concerning given the immense capacity mine has (Core i9 13900). The entire shell drops to around 2-3FPS
2. Neither Blender nor Chromium detect my GPU, making the additional drivers really rather pointless
3. Just before writing this question, my system wouldn't boot at all. (No splash-screen, no BIOS option or anything. The backlight on my monitors comes on, but that's it).

- I had to physically disconnect the GPU, boot, uninstall the drivers, reinstall the card and reboot (don't worry, I shut down and disconnected power between the various hardware-modification procedures). The system now boots but the GPU servers virtually no purpose in its current state.

I should mention that at no point did any physical damage to the GPU become apparent. The fans spin up very quickly and the card gets expectedly warm.

Upon the first insertion of the card, the bootscreen showed an error referencing a failed GPU initialisation, which after the first installation of `amdgpu` has since disappeared.

Below is (hopefully) all information which may be relevant to any advice you guys may have as to

1. How I can get my system to recognise my GPU
2. Why dafuq does Plasma (kwin) consume so much CPU in Wayland mode (XOrg works just fine but for various reasons is inadequate for me)
3. How can I test whether my GPU is installed and working without having to open Blender and doing benchmark tests etc?

```
Operating System: KDE neon 5.27
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.110.0
Qt Version: 5.15.10
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-33-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 32 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i9-13900
Memory: 31,1 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
Manufacturer: ASUS
```

### Edit: Provide `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (RPL-S)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

### Provide `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon RX 7900 XT (gfx1100, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.49, 6.2.0-33-generic)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Post `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

Comment: Thanks. Please see edit

Comment: You're running Intel now. Post `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL` for additional discrete GPU info

Comment: Thanks. Again, see edit

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.    *FYI:   KDE Neon does share a number of support options common with Kubuntu, alas this is not one of them with Neon off-topic here*

Comment: Ah thank you, I was not aware that AskUbuntu didn't accept Ubuntu derivates

Comment: Only the base of your system is LTS (ie. Ubuntu Server), to achieve a later KDE Plasma release (than available in Kubuntu backports) the libraries & toolkits (esp. Qt5 & KF5) need upgrading which come from later non-LTS releases; ie. you're not any specific release but a combination of Ubuntu releases  (*why you can have problems with many LTS packages that Kubuntu/Ubuntu users won't have*)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank u sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AMD GPU activates correctly using `DRI_PRIME=1` environment variable. So you could make your programs run off discrete GPU using this command template: `DRI_PRIME=1 blender`.

AMD's drivers are not necessary to install as `amdgpu` is integrated into the kernel.

High CPU usage might be caused by bugs in KDE itself.

Comment: I can't quickly find the executable for blender, but running this with Microsoft Edge (don't ask, it's for work) XWayland crashes

Comment: That's likely a bug somewhere. KDE neon is pretty bleeding edge. I think Ubuntu Gnome could work better

Comment: Granted KDE Neon isn't known for its stability, but admittedly if other RX 7* GPUs work reliably, which according to Reddit seems to be the case, then I don't understand how a GPU in the same series can be so much different to cause the entire program to crash

Comment: Does GPU work with Xorg?

Comment: It seems to, but every time I change to XOrg it messes all my settings up, so I try to avoid it

Comment: You should find crash logs somewhere, I'm not that knowledgeable in that

Comment: Okay I'll go look for them. Perhaps this is best handled by KDE devs

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the help of various people (@RA - lookin' at you here mate) I was able to get closer to the issue. I'm back in Wayland mode now with all programs detecting the GPU and running smoothly.

Thanks to [this post and a few others](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434988/blender-3-3-does-not-recognize-my-gpu-for-hip-on-ubuntu-20-04), it turns out one of the things I hadn't checked was whether I was running into permission issues. Running Blender undo sudo shows the GPU in the options menu.

Quick fix was to add user to the `video` and `render` groups.

Not a solution I'd've thought up, but one which works and isn't too invasive. Hope this helps others